# How to check if in one xml file a child node equals to a node in another xml file?

Tags: c#, xml

I need to generate frequently a `XML(A)`.

The structure of `XML(A)` is not changeable. I can only change my `XML(B)`. Also I could store `XML(B)` in a other `file/database/...`

When `XML(A)` is generated. I need to check if one child node(`<id></id>`) of `XML(A)` is in my `XML(B)`.

- When it is in my `XML(B)` I want to remove the whole parent node in my `XML(A)`.
- When it is not in my `XML(B)` I want to add the child node of `XML(A)` in `XML(B)`.

---

**XML(A-Before)**

```
<OPENCD>
<label>
<name>Alpha</name>
<cd>
<id>123</id>
</cd>
</label>

<label>
<name>BETA</name>
<cd>
<id>789</id>
</cd>
</label>

<label>
<name>GAMMA</name>
<cd>
<id>456</id>
</cd>
</label>
</OPENCD>
```

**XML(B-Before)**

```
<objektid>
<id>123</id>
<id>456</id>
</objektid>
```

Result should look like this

**XML(A-After)**

```
<OPENCD>
<label>
<name>BETA</name>
<cd>
<id>789</id>
</cd>
</label>
</OPENCD>
```

**XML(B-After)**

```
<objektid>
<id>123</id>
<id>456</id>
<id>789</id>
</objektid>
```

**My Testcode looks now like this:**
THX cptwonton for your advise with XDocument.

```
namespace ConsoleApp16
{
   class Program
   {
       static void Main(string[] args)
       {
           XNodeEqualityComparer comparer = new XNodeEqualityComparer();
           XDocument docA = XDocument.Load("XMLA.xml");
           XDocument docB = XDocument.Load("XMLB.xml");
           Dictionary<int, XNode> nodeDictionary = new Dictionary<int, XNode>();

           SchleifeB();
           SchleifeA();
           docA.Save("XMLA.xml");
           Console.ReadLine();

           void SchleifeB()
           {
               foreach (XNode nodeB in docB.Elements("objektid").Elements("id"))
               {
                   int hash = comparer.GetHashCode(nodeB);

                   nodeDictionary.Add(hash, nodeB);
                   Console.WriteLine("Eintrag in Dictonary hinzugefügt B");
                   Console.WriteLine(nodeB);                        
               }
           }

           void SchleifeA()
           {
               foreach (XNode nodeA in docA.Elements("OPENCD").Elements("label").Elements("cd").Elements("id"))
               {
                   int hashA = comparer.GetHashCode(nodeA);
                   if (nodeDictionary.ContainsKey(hashA))
                   {
                       Console.WriteLine("Duplikat gefunden A");
                       Console.WriteLine(nodeA);
                       nodeA.Parent.Parent.Remove();
                       //nodeA.Parent.Parent.Remove(); breaks the foreach. But I want it to loop trough each element to the end of my xmlA.
                   }
                   else
                   {
                       nodeDictionary.Add(hashA, nodeA);
                       Console.WriteLine("Eintrag in Dictonary hinzugefügt A");
                       Console.WriteLine(nodeA);
                       //Here I will add that nodeA gets pasted into XMLB
                   }
               }
           }
       }
   } 
}
```

The problem is that `node.parent.parent.Remove();` breaks the foreach-loop and only the first found duplicate gets deleted in `XML(A)`.

Comment: This isn't a public free code writing service. Please show us what you have tried so far

Comment: Hello Rollstuhlfahrer, that was not my intention.

Answer (score 0):

One approach you could to take is to:

- parse both XML A and XML B files using the XElement library's Load method. You'll get two strings as a result.
- perform comparisons (see if id in A is in B, etc etc). One way to do this is by using a regular expression but that is probably overkill. You'll probably be fine with just using the string.contains() method.
- modify the string representations of XML A and XML B
- write the strings back into the XMLs when you're done

OR, you can use the XmlDocument library to read and manipulate an XML document directly. There are guides on how to do this online.

If I were you, I'd use the XmlDocument library.

Comment: Thank you for your advice! I will try XmlDocument libary. I read some posts about XmlDocument. But I could only find out how to delete duplicates with the same datastructure.

Comment: thx cptwonton. I added now my test code. It just breaks my foreach now...